# Homework with strings

Tags: python-3.x, string, reverse

Hello guys i got a homework where i get a string and basically i should change the letters in it then return it backward:

A --> T

T --> A

G --> C

C --> G

Here is my code :

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    newWord = ""

    for x in s:
        if x == "T":
            newWord.join('A')
        elif x == "A":
            newWord.join('T')
        elif x == "C":
            newWord.join('G')
        elif x == "G":
            newWord.join('C')
    return newWord[::-1]
```

the input is: ACCGGGTTTT

Comment: `newWord.join(...)` doesn't change the value of network, so to begin with, you need to do something like `network = newWord.join(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your effort so far has got a minor issue with it.

You are using `newWord.join('X')` in an attempt to add the new character to the string.  This doesn't work in the way you are attempting to use it.  Read again how `join` functions in the [official documentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join).

Instead, you can use the `+=` operator to append the characters to the end of your `newWord` string:

```
newWord += 'X'
```

Your code then becomes:

```
def dnaComplement(s):
    newWord = ""

    for x in s:
      if x == "T":
        newWord += 'A'
      elif x == "A":
        newWord += 'T'
      elif x == "C":
        newWord += 'G'
      elif x == "G":
        newWord += 'C'

    return newWord[::-1]

print(dnaComplement('ACCGGGTTTT'))
```

Output:

```
AAAACCCGGT
```

This is the reverse of `TGGCCCAAA` which is stored in `newWord` until you return it from `dnaComplement`.

Answer (score 1):

`newWord.join(...)` doesn't change the value of `network`, but rather returns a new string.

So to begin with, you would need to do something like `network = newWord.join(...)`.

That being said, here is a cleaner way IMO:

```
d = {'T': 'A',
     'A': 'T',
     'C': 'G',
     'G': 'C'
}

def dnaComplement(s):
    return ''.join(d[x] for x in s[::-1])
```